# Submit a partial form through jQuery-ui dialog without redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm filling out a form on one page that requires registered members. If an entry is supplied without a matching member, then a dialog window pops up to add them to the database. The goal is to have the modal window close without reloading or redirecting the page to prevent any previously entered data from being wiped. I'm working on Rails 5 and I'm using the dialog modal included in jQuery-ui.

I've narrow down the issue to my partial. The dialog is pulling the partial for another model (participants), and on any successful creation, it redirects back to that page. Outside of creating a separate and redundant form, I'm not sure how to stop the redirect on the dialog window without interfering with the partial's normal behavior. I tried to see if doing a simple `redirect_back` command we help, but it still wiped out the previous data.

participants_controller.rb:

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @member = Participant.new(member_params)
    if @member.save
      flash.now[:notice] = "#{@member.badge} has been added."
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "#{@member.badge} already exists."
    end
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

_addmember.html.erb

```
<%= form_with url: participants_path, model: @participant, id: "member_submit" do |form| %>
  <div class="member_info">Badge: <%= form.number_field "member[badge]", {required: true} %></div><br>
  <div class="member_info">Name: <%= form.text_field "member[name]", {required: true} %></div><br>
  <div class="member_info">Phone: <%= form.telephone_field "member[phone]" %></div><br>
  <div class="member_info">Email: <%= form.text_field "member[email]" %></div><br>
  <div class="member_info">Preference: <%= form.select "member[pref]", ["Text", "Call", "Email"] %></div><br>
  <div class="member_info">Proxy Info: Yes<%= form.radio_button "member[proxy]", :true %>
  No<%= form.radio_button "member[proxy]", :false %></div>
<% end %>
```

Game Log - new.html.erb

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="badge_0"]').prop('required',true);
    $('#dialog_addmember').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      width: 700,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Add non-registered Participant",
          click: function() {
            if ($("form#member_submit")[0].checkValidity()) {
              $("form#member_submit").submit();
              alert($("form#member_submit > div > input")[0].value + " has been added.");
              $(this).dialog("close");
            } else {
              alert("Please ensure both badge and name are provided.");
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    $('.column_badge').change(function () {
      console.log($(this).val());
      //Modal box
      $.ajax ({
        url: "/check_entry/" + $(this)[0].value,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        error: function(data) {
          $('#dialog_addmember').dialog( "open" );
        }
      })
    });
  });
</script>
<section id="log_header">
  <%= form_with(url: game_logs_path) do |f| %>
    <div id="game_header">
      <%= f.label :inventory_id, "Game Title: " %>
      <%= f.collection_select :inventory_id, Inventory.all, :id, :game_selection, {prompt: true}, {required: true} %></div>
    <div id="detail_header">
      <%= f.label :timestamp, "Timestamp:" %>
      <%= f.datetime_select :timestamp, ampm: true, default: Time.now %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: (@event_info[0]["id"]) %>
    </div>
</section>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="entry"></th>
        <th>Badge ID</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
      </tr>
      <% 12.times do |e| %>
        <tr>
          <td class="entry"><%= "Entry #{e + 1}" %></td>
          <td><div class="badge"><%= f.number_field :badge_id, name: "badge_#{e}", class: "column_badge" %></div></td>
          <td><div class="rating">
          <% 5.times do |r| %>
              <%= "#{r + 1}" %>
              <%= f.radio_button "rating_#{e}", (r + 1) %>
          <% end %>
          </div></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>

<div id="dialog_addmember" title="Add non-registered Participant">
    <%= render "shared/addmember" %>
</div>
```

Instead of returning to the previous page without reloading data, it redirects to the participants page. Is there any way to prevent the redirect when closing the dialog modal after a successful submit?

Comment: Submit form using ajax if you want to stay on same page

Comment: I think [this tutorial](http://www.benkirane.ch/ajax-bootstrap-modals-rails/) could help you.

Comment: @matiss I'm not using Bootstrap, and the tutorial you linked is for Rails 4.

Comment: @charlietfl Can you provide any more details?

Comment: Lots of tutorials/examples around of using axax to submit forms  Also see jQuery docs https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/